# What happens in redundant function calls?

Tags: python

Very simple question, but it is a curiosity for me...

Say we have a list of items which are strings. If we call the built-in function `str` on each element in the list, that would seem to be redundant since the items are already strings. What would happen under the hood, specifically for Python but interested in other languages as well. Would the interpreter already see that the item is a string and not call the `str` function? Or would it do it anyway and return a string, and what would a string of a string mean?

Comment: Python doesn't do as much compile-time optimization as other languages, one of the big reasons why is because of the everything-is-an-object model, the lack of static typing meaning anything can become anything or not be present at all, etc. Probably the function `str` checks to see if it is already a string and does nothing if it is.

Comment: Then, for example, would gcc optimize C++ code?

Comment: Since the name `str` can be rebound to another function at runtime, there is no way for any Python implementation to know that the function bound to `str` should return a string object, and so the function *must* be called.

Comment: Thank you, that aspect of runtime coding really just hit me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When invoking `str` on a string object, the underlying function `__str__(self)` will be executed. Whether to return the original object (the python string case) or a copy depends on the implementation of the function.

Generally speaking, the language will not do or do little to handle redundant calls I think. The program itself will decide the behavior. (i.e. whether a named function is defined on the object, if not an error will be issued.)

Let's think another way. If you have some knowledge about C++, in C++ there is a kind of copy constructor. It goes similarly facing the deep copy and shadow copy problem relying on your implementation.

Comment: Thank you. So does reducing redundant calls count as lazy programming? Is that what programmers refer to in functional programming?

Comment: @Edgar Aroutiounian Lazy programming is something completely different - laziness is not evaluating anything until the moment the result of evaluating it is needed, and no sooner.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Not quite. Only if the function is idempotent, can it be reduced. Or the optimization is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Testing is simple:

```
>>> a = 'a'
>>> id(a)
4298835424
>>> id(str(a))
4298835424
>>> a is str(a)
True
```

It is the identical object.

Tested and works with CPython 2.7., 3.3., PyP 1.9., IronPython 2.0

Does **NOT** work with Jython 2.5:

```
Jython 2.5.2 (Release_2_5_2:7206, Mar 2 2011, 23:12:06) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Apple Inc.)] on java1.6.0_45
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 'a'
>>> id(a)
2
>>> id(str(a))
3
>>> id(str(a))
4
>>> a is str(a)
False
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily true (but almost certainly is) for other implementations, though.

Comment: Added some more tests. Jython is the only exception I found so far.

Comment: Interesting. Either Java's garbage collection and/or Jython's architecture seems to make it simpler to always return a new object rather than to test if the input object can be returned.

Answer (score 1):

If the data type is immutable and already of the same type, then Python simply returns back the original, same as with tuple for example.

```
>>> help(str)
Help on class str in module __builtin__:

class str(basestring)
 |  str(object='') -> string
 |  
 |  Return a nice string representation of the object.
 |  If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed by the language definition, or just commonly (universally?) implemented this way?

Comment: @chepner guaranteed by the language (wouldn't make sense not to), see the updated help doc as well

Comment: That just proves that this implementation of `str` returns the same object. I'm not sure there is anything that *requires* this to be true (although I agree, I can't think of a reason not to).

Comment: Possibly relevant: if you pass an instance of a *subclass* of `str`, it does *not* return the same object, even though that object is an instance of `str` already.

Answer (score 1):

Python calls `str`:

```
dis.dis(compile("str('a')", '<none>', 'eval'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (str)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('a')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

But this just returns the same string:

```
In [11]: str('a') is 'a'
Out[11]: True
```

*Quite often the first thing to check in class `__init__` is whether it's already an instance of the class (and if so just return it as is)...*

Comment: How does this `dis` prove anything? It just shows the function being called and returning a value. eg. `dis.dis(compile("tuple('a')", '<none>', 'eval'))` is the same as this

Comment: @jamylak which proves that it is being called. Which is what the OP asks :)

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I overlooked that part